# Help proving $I^2$ is a principal ideal and $I$ isn't with $I=(x,y-1)$ in the ring $R := \mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, polynomial-rings

So we have this ring $R := \mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$ with an ideal $I=(x,y-1)$ generated by the elements $x$ and $y-1$. I'm having trouble proving that $I^2=(x^2,x(y-1),(y-1)^2)$ is a principal ideal, because the gcd of those elements is 1. But the ideal $I^2=(1)$ is just $R$, so I dont know if that's a principal ideal. I'm also having trouble proving that $I$ is not a principal ideal, because their gcd is also $1$. So if I say that it isn't a principal ideal because their gcd is $1$ then i'm contradicting my first "proof". Is there any chance my ideal $I^2$ is wrong, from what I understood the square of an ideal generated by 2 elements $a,b$ is (a^2,ab,b^2), but I may be wrong. Does anybody have any tips?

Comment: Hint: In $R$ we have $x^2=1-y^2=(1-y)(1+y)$

Comment: Yes that was something I didn't see, I didn't know that $x^2+y^2-1=0$

Answer (score 3):

Actually $I^2 \neq (1)$ (indeed the gcd of $x$ and $y-1$ is $1$ so if your argument were correct we'd have $I = R$, which is not the case because $R/I \cong \mathbb{R} \neq 0$.). This idea only works in Euclidean domains, where you can use the division algorithm to prove that $(a,b) = (\gcd(a,b))$. There is no division algorithm in $R$, so that doesn't hold here!

To clarify a couple points from your post:

- $R$ certainly is a principal ideal of $R$. Remember that a principal ideal is just any ideal of the form $(r) = \{rx : x \in R\}$ for some $r \in R$. Since $R = (1)$, this is principal.
- You're correct that $(a,b)^2 = (a^2, ab, b^2)$. Indeed, generally we have that $(x_1, \dots, x_n)^2$ is the ideal generated by all products $x_i x_j$ where $i,j \in \{1, \dots, n\}$. You should try to prove this! Hint: show both sets are subsets of one another.

Anyway, to show that $I^2$ is principal, you should try to find some element $p \in R$ such that the image of $I$ is $0$ under the quotient $R \to R/(p)$ – this will tell you that $I^2 \subseteq (p)$, and you will only need to prove $p \in I^2$ to conclude that $I^2 = (p)$. To show that $I$ is not principal, you could try to argue by contradiction: e.g. it's possible to prove that $R/(p) \not\cong \mathbb{R} \cong R/I$ for any $p \in R$ (first of all, if $R/(p) \cong \mathbb{R}$ then $(p)$ is maximal...).

If you know anything about algebraic geometry, you can gain a lot of intuition here by noting that $R$ is the coordinate ring of the circle.

Comment: I figured out how to prove $I^2$ is a principal ideal, but i'm having trouble following your aproach to proving $I$ is not a principal ideal, could you maybe elaborate please?

Comment: +1 for that last sentence (and the explanations).

Comment: @SjaakRoosenboom On second thought, I think there's an easier way to show that $I$ is not principal than the one I mentioned. Just suppose for contradiction that $I$ is principal, so $(x, y-1) = I = (p)$ for some $p$. This means that $p$ divides both $x$ and $y-1$ in $R$, so more explicitly we have $x = pa + r(x^2 + y^2 - 1)$ and $y-1 = pb + s(x^2 + y^2 -1)$ in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ for some $a, b, r, s \in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$. Now show that this is impossible by thinking about what those polynomials on the right-hand sides will look like!

Comment: I'll try that, thx for the tip!

Comment: @diracdeltafunk, I tried writing it out but I dont seem to find an impossibility, do I have to use that $x^2+y^2-1=0$?

Comment: There might be a slight point of confusion here: remember that the elements of $R$ are actually cosets, and not literally polynomials. However, it very quickly gets cumbersome to write everything as cosets, so we usually denote elements of $R$ by their representatives in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$. However, the whole point is that each coset will have multiple representatives, so this representation is not unique! For example, $x^2+y^2-1$ and $0$ are both elements of the coset $(x^2+y^2-1)$, and therefore represent the same element of $R$. This is what we mean when we say that $x^2+y^2-1=0$ *in $R$*.

Comment: (cont.) With that out of the way, suppose $(x,y-1) = (p)$ in $R$. This means that $x$ and $y$ are divisible by $p$ in $R$, which is another way of saying there exist elements $a,b\in R$ such that $x=pa$ and $y=pb$. Equivalently, $x-pa=0$ and $y-pb=0$. But remember that the elements of $R$ are really cosets! If we think about $x,y,p,a,b$ as polynomials, this really means that $x-pa$ and $y-pb$ are elements of the coset of $0$ (aka $(x^2+y^2-1)$). In other words, saying $(x,y-1)$ is principal is equivalent to saying that there exist $p,a,b\in\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ such that $x-pa,y-pb\in(x^2+y^2-1)$

Comment: (cont.) So, what does it mean to have $x-pa\in(x^2+y^2-1)$? Well $(x^2+y^2-1)=\{(x^2+y^2-1)r:r\in\mathbb{R}[x,y]\}$, so we can equivalently say there exists $r\in\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ such that $x-pa = r(x^2+y^2-1)$. In other words, $x = pa + r(x^2+y^2-1)$. Likewise, we get $y-1 = pb + s(x^2+y^2-1)$ for some $s\in\mathbb{R}[x,y]$. These are now questions about literal equalities of polynomials, and we're working in the very concrete ring $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$! Personally this makes me much more comfortable when trying to manipulate things.

Comment: (cont.) Also, notice that since we were free to choose any representatives of the original cosets we can pick $p,a,b$ to each be of the form $f+yg$ where $f,g\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ (try to understand why there must be a representative of each coset of this form!) Now try evaluating the polynomial equalities at different values of $x,y$, comparing degrees w.r.t. $x$ and/or $y$, or really doing anything you want to try to get a contradiction! I promise it's possible, because $(x,y-1)$ really is not principal and we've just reduced that to a concrete statement about polynomial multiplication :)

Comment: Another possible argument: if $x \in \langle p \rangle$ then $p(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$ has at most simple zeros at $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\theta = \frac{3\pi}{2}$, and at no other zeros in $[0, 2\pi)$.  If $y-1 \in \langle p \rangle$ then $p(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$ has at most a double zero at $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and no other zero in $[0, 2\pi)$.  So, if both happen, then $p(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$ has at most a single zero at $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and nowhere else in $[0, 2\pi)$, which is impossible for a continuous $2\pi$-periodic function on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Oh, and a missing piece in my previous comment: from $p \in \langle x, y-1 \rangle$ you would also conclude that $p(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$ must have a zero at $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$.